# How to make MacOS Safari autoplay a video?

Tags: html, css

The video autoplays well everywhere, even mobile, except for MacOS's Safari.
I think all the necessary attributes are there, so im totally out of ideas.

What should I tweak/add to make the video autoplay on MacOS Safari?

```html
    <div class="videoBackground">
    <video preload="auto" muted autoplay loop playsinline>
    <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/svb6t3bxnwsqvx3/Sweet_Home_mini.mp4?dl=0" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  var height = $(window).height();
  $(".videoBackground")
    .width(width)
    .height(height);
});

$(window).resize(t_throttle(function() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  var height = $(window).height();
  $(".videoBackground")
    .width(width)
    .height(height);
}));
</script>

<style>
.videoBackground > video {
  object-fit: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
</style>
```

Comment: I am also struggling with this and it seems no one else needs it.

I made a quick test with different attributes: https://codepen.io/mattweb/pen/vYjBaZW?editors=1000

In iOS Safari it even autoplays with muted and playsinline attributes. And mostly you find problems from people where it does not play on iPhones. I don't get it :(

Comment: Om my coworkers macOS Safari it works. Videos 2 and 3 autoplay. So it is not a general problem. We both have 15.6.1.